# UK Cities SQL

Tags: sql, geolocation

Does anybody have a script for inserting a list of UK towns cities into a SQL server database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a quich VB using the excellent link which "Machine" provided. I copied and pasted the results

Here is the code

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim s As String = "Abberley | Abbey Wood | Abbots Bromley | Abbots Langley | Abbots Leigh | Abbots Ripton | Abbotsbury | Abbotsley | Aberaeron | Aberargie | Abercastle | Abercraf | Abercych | Aberdare | Aberdaron | Aberdeen | Aberdour | Aberdovey | Aberfeldy | Aberffraw | Aberfoyle | Abergavenny | Abergele | Abergorlech | Abergwili | Aberlady | Aberlour | Abernethy | Aberporth | Abersoch | Abersychan | Abertillery | Aberystwyth | Abingdon | Abinger | Abinger Hammer | Abington | Aboyne | Abram | Abridge | Acaster Malbis | Accrington | Acharacle | Achiltibuie | Achnasheen | Acklam | Ackworth | Acle | Acocks Green | Acomb | Acrefair | Acton | Acton Bridge | Adare | Adderbury | Addingham | Addington | Addlestone | Adlington | Adstock | Aghadowey | Aghalee | Ahoghill | Airdrie | Airth | Akebar | Akeley | Albrighton | Albury | Alcester | Alconbury | Alconbury Weston | Aldbourne | Aldbrough St John | Aldbury | Aldeburgh | Aldenham | Alderbury | Alderley Edge | Aldermaston | Alderminster | Alderney | Aldersey Green | Aldershot | Aldford | Aldgate | Aldridge | Aldringham | Aldworth | Aldwych | Alexandria | Alfold | Alford | Alfreton | Alfriston | All of London | All Stretton | Allendale | Allenheads | Allerford | Allerston | Allerton | Allhallows | Allhallows-on-Sea | Allington | Alloa | Allostock | Alloway | Almeley | Almondbank | Almondsbury | Alne | Alness | Alnmouth | Alnwick | Alresford | Alrewas | Alsager | Alsagers Bank | Alston | Alstonefield | Althorne | Althorp | Altnagelvin | Alton | Alton Towers | Altrincham | Alum Bay | Alva | Alvechurch | Alvecote | Alvediston | Alveley | Alves | Alveston | Alvington | Alwoodley | Alyth | Ambergate | Amberley | Amble | Ambleside | Ambrosden | Amersham | Amesbury | Amlwch | Ammanford | Ampfield | Ampleforth | Ampthill | Amroth | Amulree | Ancaster | Anderton | Andover | Andoversford | Angle | Angmering | Annacloy | Annalong | Annan | Annbank | Anniesland | Annitsford | Anslow | Anstruther | Ansty | Antrim | Apartments all over London | Apperley Bridge | Appin | Applecross | Appledore | Appletreewick | Appley | Apsley | Arborfield | Arbroath | Archway | Arclid | Ardaneaskan | Ardbeg | Ardeley | Ardens Grafton | Ardentinny | Ardeonaig | Ardfern | Ardgay | Ardglass | Ardingly | Ardington | Ardishaig | Ardleigh | Ardmillan | Ardrishaig | Ardrossan | Ardvasar | Arisaig | Arkendale | Arkengarthdale | Arkesden | Arklow | Arlesey | Arlingham | Arlington | Armadale | Armagh | Armathwiate | Armoy | Armscote | Armthorpe | Arncliffe | Arncott | Arnold | Arnside | Aros | Arreton | Arrochar | Arthingworth | Articlave | Artigarvan | Arundel | Ascog Bay | Ascot | Ash | Ash-cum-Ridley | Ashbourne | Ashburnham Place | Ashburton | Ashcott | Ashford | Ashford in the Water | Ashford-in-the-Water | Ashill | Ashington | Ashkirk | Ashleworth | Ashley | Ashmore Green | Ashorne | Ashover | Ashprington | Ashtead | Ashton | Ashton in Makerfield | Ashton Keynes | Ashton under Lyne | Ashton-in-Makerfield | Ashton-under-Lyne | Ashurst | Ashwater | Ashwell | Ashwicke | Askam-in-Furness | Askernish | Askett | Askham | Askrigg | Aspatria | Aspley Guise | Asthall | Astmoor | Aston | Aston Cantlow | Aston Clinton | Aston Rowant | Astwood | Athelstaneford | Atherstone | Atherton | Athlone | Athy | Attleborough | Auchenblae | Auchenbowie | Auchencairn | Auchindoir | Auchinleck | Auchterarder | Auchtermuchty | Audlem | Aughnacloy | Aughrim | Aughton | Auldearn | Auldgirth | Aultbea | Aust | Austerfield | Austrey | Austwick | Avebury | Aveley | Avening | Aviemore | Avonwick | Awre | Axbridge | Axford | Axminster | Axmouth | Aycliffe | Aylesbury | Aylesford | Aylesham | Aylmerton | Aylsham | Aymestrey | Aynho | Ayot St Lawrence | Ayr | Aysgarth | Ayside |"
        Dim cities() As String = s.Split("|")

        Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
        oWrite = File.CreateText("C:\uktowns_sql.txt")

        For Each city As String In cities
            oWrite.WriteLine("INSERT INTO mytable values(" & """" & city.Trim() & """" & ")")
        Next

        oWrite.Flush()
        oWrite.Close()


    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the result. Just change the table name

```
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abberley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbey Wood")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbots Bromley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbots Langley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbots Leigh")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbots Ripton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbotsbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abbotsley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberaeron")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberargie")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abercastle")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abercraf")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abercych")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberdare")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberdaron")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberdeen")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberdour")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberdovey")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberfeldy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberffraw")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberfoyle")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abergavenny")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abergele")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abergorlech")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abergwili")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberlady")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberlour")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abernethy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberporth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abersoch")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abersychan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abertillery")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aberystwyth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abingdon")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abinger")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abinger Hammer")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aboyne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abram")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Abridge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acaster Malbis")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Accrington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acharacle")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Achiltibuie")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Achnasheen")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acklam")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ackworth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acle")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acocks Green")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acomb")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acrefair")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Acton Bridge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Adare")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Adderbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Addingham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Addington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Addlestone")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Adlington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Adstock")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aghadowey")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aghalee")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ahoghill")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Airdrie")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Airth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Akebar")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Akeley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Albrighton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Albury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alcester")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alconbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alconbury Weston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldbourne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldbrough St John")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldeburgh")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldenham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alderbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alderley Edge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldermaston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alderminster")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alderney")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldersey Green")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldershot")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldgate")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldridge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldringham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldworth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aldwych")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alexandria")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alfold")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alfreton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alfriston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("All of London")
INSERT INTO mytable values("All Stretton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allendale")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allenheads")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allerford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allerston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allerton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allhallows")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allhallows-on-Sea")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alloa")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Allostock")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alloway")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Almeley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Almondbank")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Almondsbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alness")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alnmouth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alnwick")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alresford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alrewas")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alsager")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alsagers Bank")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alstonefield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Althorne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Althorp")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Altnagelvin")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alton Towers")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Altrincham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alum Bay")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alva")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alvechurch")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alvecote")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alvediston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alveley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alves")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alveston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alvington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alwoodley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Alyth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ambergate")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amberley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amble")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ambleside")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ambrosden")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amersham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amesbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amlwch")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ammanford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ampfield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ampleforth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ampthill")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amroth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Amulree")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ancaster")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Anderton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Andover")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Andoversford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Angle")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Angmering")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Annacloy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Annalong")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Annan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Annbank")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Anniesland")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Annitsford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Anslow")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Anstruther")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ansty")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Antrim")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Apartments all over London")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Apperley Bridge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Appin")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Applecross")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Appledore")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Appletreewick")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Appley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Apsley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arborfield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arbroath")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Archway")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arclid")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardaneaskan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardbeg")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardeley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardens Grafton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardentinny")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardeonaig")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardfern")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardgay")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardglass")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardingly")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardishaig")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardleigh")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardmillan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardrishaig")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardrossan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ardvasar")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arisaig")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arkendale")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arkengarthdale")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arkesden")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arklow")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arlesey")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arlingham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arlington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armadale")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armagh")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armathwiate")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armoy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armscote")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Armthorpe")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arncliffe")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arncott")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arnold")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arnside")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aros")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arreton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arrochar")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arthingworth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Articlave")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Artigarvan")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Arundel")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ascog Bay")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ascot")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ash")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ash-cum-Ridley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashbourne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashburnham Place")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashburton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashcott")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashford in the Water")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashford-in-the-Water")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashill")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashkirk")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashleworth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashmore Green")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashorne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashover")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashprington")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashtead")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton in Makerfield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton Keynes")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton under Lyne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton-in-Makerfield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashton-under-Lyne")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashurst")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashwater")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashwell")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ashwicke")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Askam-in-Furness")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Askernish")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Askett")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Askham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Askrigg")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aspatria")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aspley Guise")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Asthall")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Astmoor")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aston")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aston Cantlow")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aston Clinton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aston Rowant")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Astwood")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Athelstaneford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Atherstone")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Atherton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Athlone")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Athy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Attleborough")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchenblae")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchenbowie")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchencairn")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchindoir")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchinleck")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchterarder")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auchtermuchty")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Audlem")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aughnacloy")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aughrim")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aughton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auldearn")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Auldgirth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aultbea")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aust")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Austerfield")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Austrey")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Austwick")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Avebury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aveley")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Avening")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aviemore")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Avonwick")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Awre")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Axbridge")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Axford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Axminster")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Axmouth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aycliffe")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aylesbury")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aylesford")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aylesham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aylmerton")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aylsham")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aymestrey")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aynho")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ayot St Lawrence")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ayr")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Aysgarth")
INSERT INTO mytable values("Ayside")
INSERT INTO mytable values("")
```

Comment: It would be much quicker if you used a single insert-statement like: INSERT INTO mytable values ("Abberley"), ("Abbey Wood"), [...]

Comment: @Machine-Excuse my ignorance, but what DB Engine takes an insert like that? (this is a sincere question, I expect the answer is MySQL, but wanted to confirm since this doesn't appear to be supported in MSSQL)

Comment: You could do it in one insert by using selct and union all
Insert table1 (myfield)
select 'test'
union all
select 'test2'
etc

Comment: @HLGEM-True, but based on his sample code, I don't think that's what he's talking about.  I'd love to find out I'm wrong and this is actually possible on MSSQL

Comment: I saw the user mentioned SQL Server database.

Comment: @Saif Khan-I know the union would work, but would his sample SQL? 
INSERT INTO mytable values ("Abberley"), ("Abbey Wood"), [...]

Comment: @John MacIntyre: if you replace the double quotes with single quotes then the syntax works on SQL Server 2008. I would refer to this syntax as row constructors, though is not up to the SQL-92 syntax yet, useful as per the example here i.e. populating a table.

Comment: Hi thanks for all the info.  I wasnt actaully looking for the sql sytax - I'm fine with that, more a repository of cities as my search produced very flakey results.  Thanks Saif

Answer (score 2):

You could generate some INSERTs in MS Excel from [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_the_United_Kingdom) at Wikipedia.

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

@JohnMacintyre:

I'd use the HTML from that list you suggested at Wikipedia and then I'd use RegexBuddy to build me all the inserts which I'd then cut and paste into SQL Server Query Analyzer and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can find (all?) the towns in uk [here](http://www.information-britain.co.uk/towns.cfm).

You would need to fetch them all by looping over the letters of the alphabet, kind of like this:

```
// PHP pseudo-code
$letters = array('a', 'b', [...], 'z');
foreach($letters as $letter) {
  $html = file_get_contents(
                "http://www.information-britain.co.uk/towns.cfm?alpha=$letter");
  $towns = $this->extractTowns($html);
  $sql = $this->generateSQL($towns);
  $this->db->query($sql);
}

public function extractTowns ($html) {
   // Code to extract towns from $html. Return an array
}

public function generateSQL(array $towns) {
    // Generate SQL here from the town-list on the form
    // INSERT INTO UkTowns (columndefinitions) VALUES ($towns[x]-columns, [...])
}
```

Comment: Would you really do this in PHP? ... man that's hard core!  ;-)

Comment: Well, if you make generic enough functions, esp. generateSQL, you could reuse it for multiple town-lists. But no, I probably wouldn't if this was the only list to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I need a similar list, but with latitude and longitude too. I think I will have to copy 26 pages from here: http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~agene/locations/index.html

Normally you'd let Google store it all for you, but when you want 50 place names shown on one webpage, making 50 HTTP calls to Google's geocoding service makes the page load to slowly to keep users happy (unless I am missing a trick?).

I will have to maintain my own SQL table. Looking at old data on our system, only 2000 distinct place names have been used in the past, so I don't think things will become unmanageable.